# How to filter DataFrame by conditions in other DataFrame in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have a DataFrame `source` and want to filter out entries based on conditions in another DataFrame called `blacklist`. A `source` has to match at least one `blacklist` entry to be filtered out. The columns conditions/entries in the `blacklist` are linked by `AND`. A `NULL` value in the `blacklist` stays for a wildcard, this means the corresponding attribute can have any value to match the condition.

**A simplified example:**

**`source`**:

```
| id | age | color |
|----|-----|-------|
| 1  | 28  | blue  |
| 2  | 25  | blue  |
| 3  | 15  | red   |
| 4  | 20  | red   |
| 5  | 27  | green |
| 6  | 30  | green |
```

**`blacklist`**:

```
| age  | color |
|------|-------|
| 25   | blue  |
| NULL | red   |
| 30   | NULL  |
```

**`output`**:

```
| id | age | color |
|----|-----|-------|
| 1  | 28  | blue  |
| 5  | 27  | green |
```

The corresponding DataFrames:

```scala
val source = Seq((1, 28, "blue"), (2, 25, "blue"), (3, 15, "red"), (4, 20, "red"), (5, 27, "green"), (6, 30, "green")).toDF("id", "age", "color")
val blacklist = Seq((Some(25), Some("blue")), (None, Some("red")), (Some(30), None)).toDF("age", "color")
```

**Further information about the real data:**

- Data is stored in Hive tables (ORC format)
- `source` contains 10 billion entries
- `blacklist` contains 200 thousand entries with 5 columns

**My Approach (Using Spark 2.3):**

```scala
val joinCondition = (source("age") <=> blacklist("age") || blacklist("age").isNull) && (source("color") <=> blacklist("color") || blacklist("color").isNull)
val dataToRemove = source.join(broadcast(blacklist), joinCondition).select(source("id"), source("age"), source("color"))                                                                                    
val output = source.except(dataToRemove)
```

**Problem & Question:**

The code snippet above is working. However, I have performance problems regarding the runtime duration with the real huge data. Do you see a better approach to this blacklisting problem?

I was also thinking about creating a big filter condition in the driver and just do `source.filter(theBigCondition)`. This has the advantage that no join is necessary. However, even with a smaller blacklist I was getting issues regarding the Catalyst Optimizer.

What are your ideas?

Comment: Hmmm... performance issues can be caused by many things - both related to code but also to the hardware configuration. Your code looks quite simple, so what makes you think that the problem is with the broadcast join? You have a fairly large `source` dataset - how long does it take to run the job and what hardware configuration are you using?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have any influence on the hardware configuration. The actual run time is meaningless without any details about the actual data. I was more looking for a better approach to solve the problem in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer my own question.

In local tests I found out that the `except` is quite expensive. Adding a kind of a flag to the `source` data and later on filter by that seams to be faster.

```scala
val blacklistWithFlag = blacklist.withColumn("remove", lit(true))
val markedSource = source.join(broadcast(blacklistWithFlag), joinCondition, "left_outer").select(source("id"), source("age"), source("color"), blacklistWithFlag("remove"))
val output = markedSource.filter(col("remove").isNull).drop("remove")
```

This approach requires only 1 stage instead of 4 stages with the above.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach of join with broadcast is probably the best approach to this problem.

First try to understand which part is taking so long.
Probably it's this part :

```
val joinedDf = data.join(broadcast(blacklist))
```

So my first suspect will be *skewed* data in the 10 B Dataframe. And since your black DF is so small "Salty Join" will work great in this case.

Base of the algorithm:

Salty join is perform by choosing a number `1-N`. Than you multiply each row in the smaller DF by N. For `N=3`:

blacklist before:

```
| age  | color |
|------|-------|
| 25   | blue  |
| 30   | NULL  |
```

blacklist after:

```
| salt | age  | color |
|------|------|-------|
|   1  | 25   | blue  |
|   2  | 25   | blue  |
|   3  | 25   | blue  |
|   1  | 25   | red   |
|   2  | 25   | red   |
|   3  | 25   | red   |
```

And for the bigger DF for each row you add a random number between 1-N:

```
    | salt | age  | color |
    |------|------|-------|
    |   3  | 25   | blue  |
    |   2  | 27   | green |
    |   1  | 25   | blue  |
    |   3  | 45   | red   |
```

Than you add salt column to be a part of the join:

```
saltedData.join(brodcast(saltedBlacklist), Seq("salt","age","color"))
```

Now we can see that in the big DF we have duplicate (25, blue) but since they have different salt they will distributed to more machines.

The idea of salty join is to gain bigger entropy. If we have a really skewed data in our join columns there will be poor distribution between the workers. By adding salting we may inflate the data of the small df times N but we get better distribution by getting better entropy in our new join columns which contains "salt" column now.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Can you explain in more detail why this salty join improves the distribution when we have a broadcast join and how `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` plays a role here?

Comment: I have tested the salted join with some real production data. It was slower than without it. Thank you anyway, I will keep this approach in mind for future problems.